# Запрос на выборку

Tags: sql

Добрый день, пожалуйста, помогите составить SQL-запрос на выборку из такой базы данных информации только о тех покупателях, покупавших товары более чем из половни категорий. Мои попытки заканчиваются фейлами :(

`SELECT [Customers].CompanyName
FROM [Customers]
WHERE [Customers].CustomerId IN ( 
    SELECT [Orders].CustomerId
    FROM [Orders]
    INNER JOIN [Order Details]
    ON [Orders].OrderId = [Order Details].OrderId 
    GROUP BY [Orders].CustomerId, [Order Details].ProductId
    WHERE COUNT([Order Details].ProductId) IN (
        SELECT (COUNT([Categories].CategoryId))/2 
        FROM [Categories] 
    ) 
)`

[image: 123]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На 100% не ручаюсь, нет времени вбивать данные для проверки, но синтаксически мой вариант верен )

```
SELECT 
    C.COMPANYNAME
FROM 
    ORDERS O LEFT JOIN
    CUSTOMERS C ON C.CUSTOMERID = O.CUSTOMERID
WHERE 
    O.ORDERID IN 
    (
        SELECT
            O.ORDERID
        FROM
            ORDERS O LEFT JOIN
            ORDER_DETAILS OD ON OD.ORDERID = O.ORDERID LFET JOIN
            PRODUCTS P ON P.PRODUCTID = OD.PRODUCTID LEFT JOIN
            CATEGORIES C ON C.CATEGORYID = P.CATEGORYID
        GROUP BY 
            O.ORDERID
        HAVING
            COUNT(DISTINCT P.CATEGORYID) > (SELECT COUNT(1) from CATEGORIES) / 2
    )
```

Comment: Спасибо! Проверю - отпишусь:)

Comment: Всё правильно, но единственный момент - пишет что Orders - недопустимый объект:)

Comment: Возможно кириллический символ где-то затесался. Но с этим, я думаю, вы уж сладите.

Comment: Да-да, все проблемы уже решены:)Спасибо ещё раз